# MEAN stack login & registration

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, jwt, angular-social-login

I am creating a mean stack application and want to implement social login with Google in it. But i am not able to configure that while doing social login should i have to store that user data in my database also. Because if social logged in user tries to do jwt-auth, then that user doesn't exists.